# Multiplying lists and scalars

Tags: python

So I have a script that reads multiple values from a file, and creates lists with these values.

I have a list of fractional coordinates of atoms (where each element is a list containing x, y, z coords) and their corresponding charges in another list. I also have three values that are scalars and correspond to the dimensions I am working in.

Here is a snippet of how the lists look:

```
Coords = [[0.982309, 0.927798, 0.458125], [0.017691, 0.072202, 0.958125], [0.482309, 0.572202, 0.458125], [0.517691, 0.427798, 0.958125], [0.878457, 0.311996, 0.227878], [0.121543, 0.688004, 0.727878], [0.378457, 0.188004, 0.227878], [0.621543, 0.811996, 0.727878], [0.586004, 0.178088, 0.37778], [0.413997, 0.821912, 0.87778], [0.086003, 0.321912, 0.37778], ......]

Charges = [0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.18, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.17, 0.17, 0.17....]
```

Then I have the three dimension values that I will call a, b, c.

#### Here is what I need to calculate:

I need to do an inner (dot) product of the fractional coordinates by the dimensions, for each atom. Of this sub-list, I need to multiply the first element by a, the second element by b and the third by c. I also need to multiply each of these components by the corresponding charge. This will give me the dipole moments, that I need to finally calculate.

**Detailed example:**
So I want to take each element in the list. We'll start with element 0.
So coords[0] = [0.982309, 0.927798, 0.458125], and charge[0] = 0.18

What I want to do, is take the first element of coords[0], multiply that by a. Then the second by b, and the third by c. Then, I want to multiply each of these elements by charges[0], 0.18, and sum the three together. That gives me the dipole moment due to one atom. I want to repeat this for every atom, so coords[1] with charges[1], coords[2] with charges[2] and so forth. Then, I want to sum all of these together, and divide by `a * b * c` to give the polarization.

I'm still new to using Python, and so I am quite unsure on even where to start with this! I hope I have explained well enough, but if not I can clarify where needed.

**Side note:**
I also then need to change some of these fractional coordinates and repeat the calculation. I am fairly certain I know how to do this, here's how it would look.

```
for x in displacement
    fracCoord[0]=fracCoord[0]+x
```

So I would change the relevant values in the fractional coordinates list by constant amount before repeating the calculations.

Comment: A sample of your data and the expected output would probably make things clearer...

Comment: Of course, my apologies, will add now.

Comment: Are a, b,c constant values or will they potentially change for each set of coords?

Comment: Btw, your question is unnecessarily long, you can cut-short to the main issue and task you are getting stuck at.

Comment: a, b, c are constant. And yeah, I do often find myself over-explaining what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) package, it is designed for such (and more complex) numerical computations based on matrices and arrays.

Then, you have:

```
import numpy as np

# Assume you have N atoms.

# N x 3 matrix where each row is the coordinates of an atom
CoordsMat = np.array(Coords)
# N x 1 vector where each value is charge of atom
ChargesVec = np.array(Charges)
# 3 x 1 vector, the weights for each coordinate
dims = np.array([a, b, c])

# N x 1 vector, computes dot product for each atom's coordinates with the weights
positionVecs = np.matmul(CoordsMat, dims)
# N x 1 vector, scales each dot product by the charges vector
dipoleMoments = np.multiply(positionVecs, ChargesVec)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! 
This makes a lot of sense. I've not really touched numpy before, although I have heard of its uses. I've tried running this and seeing what it outputs, but it doesn't like the matmul command. Could that be down to the version of numpy I'm using?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Polarisation2.py", line 62, in <module>
    positionVec = np.matmul(coordsMat,dims)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matmul'

Comment: This seems to work for me just fine, try `pip install -U numpy` from the console. Also, I'm using Python 2.7.13. My `numpy` version is 1.13.1, and yes it was introduced from v1.10, refer [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

Comment: Yeah, the problem is definitely that I have an older version. Will have to work out how to uninstall and reinstall it, as it just generates errors when using pip

Comment: Just checked that you can also use `np.dot(...)` instead of `np.matmul(...)`. Please check if that works, I am getting the same results.

Comment: @user24990: I believe `np.dot()` was introduced long back, and should work. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to fix my numpy version, and now matmul is working correctly! np.dot() also gives the same results

Comment: Glad to be able to help, thank you for accepting my answer :)